# NOT and AND operation together in Regular Expression for matching numbers( like 1.0,-3,-3.0) excluding -0.0

Tags: java, regex, numbers

I want to validate an input string with RegEx which will accept all the decimal or non-decimal numbers with or without(-) sign, but -0 or, -0.00 patternshould be rejected.
To validate this, I have one regex, can call it
*expression1*= "([-]?\d+(\.\d+)?)"
and to identify -0 or -0.00 or -00.000 pattern I have another expression, call it
*expression2*= "([-][0][.]*[0]*)"
 I want to do an evaluation like - (*expression1*)&&(!(*expression2*))
I tried with below code in Java-

```
String regEx="(?=(([-]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)))(^(?=(([-][0][.]*[0]*))))";
/*String regEx="(?=(*expression1*))(^(?=(*expression2*)))"*/ 
if(Pattern.compile(regEx).matcher("-0.00").matches())
            System.out.println("true");
else System.out.println("false");
```

But for valid inputs also it is giving me false.
How to correct whichever mistake I am doing?
Note:-   Accepted values:  0,0.00,12,1.10, -0.9,-09.00;  not accepted values   -0,-0.000

Comment: Any reason why you couldn't parse to float and check for zeroes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to exclude negative zero numbers as in this regex:

```
^(?!-0+(?:\.0+)?$)-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mwwxsl/2)

PS: Note that in `.matches()` method anchors are implicit so no need to add it in regex.

Negative lookahead expression `(?!-0+(?:\.0+)?$)` will assert failure if input has just negative zeroes e.g. `-0`, `-0.00`, `-0.0` etc.

Comment: Doesn't match `0` or `0.00`

Comment: I was under impression that OP didn't want all zeroes

Comment: Only doesn't want them if negative. Try `^(?!-0+(?:\.0+)?$)-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$`

Comment: Thanks @anubhava for the quick response. The above solution by ctwheels worked.

Comment: Thanks!! @ctwheels .